# playwright scrapy cant login to site but just plawright is do

Tags: python, forms, authentication, scrapy, playwright

I want to login with scrapy_playwright in scrapy spider but it says incorrect login information
but when i try to login with just playwrigt ans without scrapy it can login.

There can be  diffrents from scrapy code inputs and playwright code inputs but think about them same credentials. It just changed for prevent data leak in code.
This is my spider:

```
class BiosSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "bios"

    def start_requests(self):

      
        yield (scrapy.Request(url="https://mysite.com.tr/LoginPage",
                              callback=self.parse,

                              meta={"playwright": True,
                                    "playwright_include_page": True,
                                    "playwright_page_methods": [
                        
                                                   PageMethod(
                                            "fill", '//div[@class="card-body"]/form[@id="uyeGirisFormBayi"]/div/input[@name="bayiKodu"]',  value="aaaaa"),
                                        

                                        PageMethod(
                                            "fill", '//div[@class="card-body"]/form[@id="uyeGirisFormBayi"]/div/input[@name="kullaniciAdi"]', value="aaaaaab"),
                                        
                                        PageMethod(
                                            "fill", '//div[@class="card-body"]/form[@id="uyeGirisFormBayi"]/div/input[@name="sifre"]', value="ccccccc"),
                                        PageMethod(
                                            "wait_for_timeout", 5*1000),
                                       
                                        PageMethod(
                                            "click", '//div[@class="card-body"]/form[@id="uyeGirisFormBayi"]/button'),
                      

                                    ]

                                    }))

    async def parse(self, response):
        print("QQQQQQQQQ", response)
        print("UUUUUUUUUU", response.request.headers['User-Agent'])
        print("HHHHHHHHHHH", response.request.headers)
        page = response.meta['playwright_page']

     
        await page.wait_for_timeout(50*1000)
```

But when i use just playwright i can login :
This is just playwright

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright


with sync_playwright() as p:
    bwo = p.chromium.launch(headless=False, slow_mo=50)
    page = bwo.new_page()
    page.goto("https://mysite.com.tr/LoginPage")
    page.locator(
        '//div[@class="card-body"]/form[@id="uyeGirisFormBayi"]/div/input[@name="bayiKodu"]'
    ).fill("aaaa"),
    page.locator(
        '//div[@class="card-body"]/form[@id="uyeGirisFormBayi"]/div/input[@name="kullaniciAdi"]').fill("bbbbbb")
    page.locator(
        '//div[@class="card-body"]/form[@id="uyeGirisFormBayi"]/div/input[@name="sifre"]').fill("ccccccc")
    page.locator(
        '//div[@class="card-body"]/form[@id="uyeGirisFormBayi"]/button').click()
    page.wait_for_timeout(500*1000)
    page.close()
```

There is no error turn back for scrapy
my settings :

```
USER_AGENT = None
REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION = "2.7"
TWISTED_REACTOR = "twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor"
FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING = "utf-8"


PLAYWRIGHT_LAUNCH_OPTIONS = {"headless": False}

DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS = {
    "http": "scrapy_playwright.handler.ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler",
    "https": "scrapy_playwright.handler.ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler",
}
TWISTED_REACTOR = "twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor"

# timeout zamanı
PLAYWRIGHT_DEFAULT_NAVIGATION_TIMEOUT = 600*1000
```

i downt know what i'm missing
please hep me

for fill the question :

Answer (score 0):

it's done.

As of scrapy project send request headers for scrapy settings i can't login.
so must use playwright's headers in requests.
to do that in settings.py add these line

```
PLAYWRIGHT_PROCESS_REQUEST_HEADERS = None
```

This setting is use for playwrights request headers.

On the docs:

> Setting PLAYWRIGHT_PROCESS_REQUEST_HEADERS=None will give complete
> control to Playwright, i.e. headers from Scrapy requests will be
> ignored and only headers set by Playwright will be sent. Keep in mind
> that in this case, headers passed via the Request.headers attribute or
> set by Scrapy components are ignored (including cookies set via the
> Request.cookies attribute).

Thank you